# how to set value in arraylist without loading whole page..?

Tags: html, hibernate, jsp, struts, struts2-jquery

I am developing web application using struts2 hibernate. How to set a value in arraylist without loading the other. Front end is JSP Page. That page has multiple arraylist. Thank you in advance..

Comment: please post your code what you have tried?so that easy to sort out your issue.

Comment: @Jegatheesh try using JSON with struts2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Jegatheesh,**

Your requirement is very much similar to what I have implemented few days back in my project, where I have to pass an arraylist from JSP page to my struts Action class. So I used **JSON** for that.

Here is the working sample of my project:-

**First make an object in javascript itself**

```
var objectDetails = {};
```

**Now add details to this object like :-**

```
objectDetails.ID = $("#ID").val();
objectDetails.Name = $("#Name").val();
objectDetails.Address = $("#Address").val();
objectDetails.Contact = $("#Contact").val();
objectDetails.MailID = $("#MailID").val();
```

**then make an array and Add this object to the array**

```
var listArray = [];
listArray.push(objectDetails);
```

**Now your JSON object is ready with all the data. All you have to do is just send it to your STRUTS Action class via JSON as follows :-**

```
$.getJSON('AddList', {
    JSONObjectString: JSON.stringify(ObjectDetails)
});
```

Here in the above code **`AddList`** is your struts action which you have to map in your **`struts.xml`** and **`JSONObjectString`** is the property name which you have to make in your action class with getters and setters.
Now just club all this code and paste into a jquery button click function.. so that you can execute it.

Comment: Thank you ... Is there any way to set json response arraylist[resonse.arrylist_name] into struts2 select statement directly....? (eg).. like this:<s:select name="slelect" list="[right_here]" />

Comment: Try to parse the JSONObjectString and save the data into a list.